# Right Typescript type for on:change handler in Svelte

Tags: typescript, svelte

I have this code:

```
<select class="form-control" on:change={pathChanged}>
```

The signature for `pathChanged` is:

```
function pathChanged(event: { target: HTMLSelectElement }) {
```

When I run that through `tsc` using `npm run check`, I get this error:

```
Error: Type '(event: { target: HTMLSelectElement; }) => void' is not assignable to type 'FormEventHandler<HTMLSelectElement>'.
  Types of parameters 'event' and 'event' are incompatible.
    Type 'Event & { currentTarget: EventTarget & HTMLSelectElement; }' is not assignable to type '{ target: HTMLSelectElement; }'.
      Types of property 'target' are incompatible.
        Type 'EventTarget | null' is not assignable to type 'HTMLSelectElement'.
          Type 'null' is not assignable to type 'HTMLSelectElement'. (ts)

<select class="form-control" on:change={pathChanged}>
```

What signature should `pathChanged` have?

Answer (score 17, accepted):

The event `target` is less specific<sup>1</sup> than you would want it to be. In this scenario I usually use a type assertion within the function to work around this.

```js
function pathChanged(event: Event) {
   const target = event.target as HTMLSelectElement;
   // ...
}
```

Though the error states that `currentTarget` should be typed correctly, so using that should work as well:

```js
function pathChanged(event: { currentTarget: HTMLSelectElement })
```

If an event has a more specific type than just `Event`, e.g. `MouseEvent`, the types can be combined using `&`:

```js
function onMouseUp(event: MouseEvent & { currentTarget: HTMLSelectElement })
```

<sub><sup>1</sup> The reason for that is that most events bubble and the `target` often can be any element within the element with the handler on it. `currentTarget` always refers to the element with the handler and thus can be typed definitively.</sub>

Answer (score 1):

I did this in an input type `file`:

```js
// added this interface
interface FormEventHandler<T> {
    target: EventTarget | null;
}

// then in the function
const onChangeFile = async (event: FormEventHandler<HTMLInputElement>) => {
    const target = event.target as HTMLInputElement;
    // your code
}
```