# I want to get the event type of a svelte on:input event in typescript but I can't find it

Tags: typescript, svelte

I have an input in svelte

```
 <input
    {type}
    {placeholder}
    on:input={(e) => emitChange(e)}
    class="pl-2 w-full h-full bg-sand border border-midnight dark:bg-midnight"
  />
```

That goes into this function

```
  function emitChange(event: any) {
    const text = event.target.value
    dispatch("changeContent", {
      text,
    })
  }
```

I want to get rid of the `any` and replace it with the correct `InputEvent` which I can see it is using console logs. but how do I find `InputEvent` from svelte?

`import { createEventDispatcher, InputEvent } from "svelte"` fails with `Module '"svelte"' has no exported member 'InputEvent'`

I tried:

```
  function emitChange(event: InputEvent) {
    console.log(event, "13rm")
    const text = event.target.value // fails here
  }
```

that gives `Property 'value' does not exist on type 'EventTarget'` even though when i console log `event` i see:

```
InputEvent {isTrusted: true, data: 'a', isComposing: false, inputType: 'insertText', dataTransfer: null, …}isTrusted: truebubbles: truecancelBubble: falsecancelable: falsecomposed: truecurrentTarget: nulldata: "a"dataTransfer: nulldefaultPrevented: falsedetail: 0eventPhase: 0inputType: "insertText"isComposing: falsereturnValue: truesourceCapabilities: nullsrcElement: input.pl-2.w-full.h-full.bg-sand.border.border-midnight.dark:bg-midnighttarget: input.pl-2.w-full.h-full.bg-sand.border.border-midnight.dark:bg-midnighttimeStamp: 1324.199999988079type: "input"view: nullwhich: 0[[Prototype]]: InputEvent '13rm'
```

and when I click to open the object I see a `target` property with a value. like this:

```
target: {
    // ...
    value: "a"
}
```

so I must have the wrong type.

Edit, this "works" to get the event type but I still have the awful `any`:

```
  function emitChange(event: any) {
    console.log(event, "13rm")
    const { value } = event.target as HTMLInputElement // improvement
    const text = value
  }
```

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Right Typescript type for on:change handler in Svelte](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/72339759/right-typescript-type-for-onchange-handler-in-svelte)

Answer (score 0):

The events emitted from native HTML elements are the same events that would be emitted when not using Svelte. Svelte does not alter these native events. So, the type of event you want for the [`input`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/HTMLInputElement#events) element is [`InputEvent`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/InputEvent), which shouldn't need to be imported in order to work.

For example:

```js
function emitChange(event: InputEvent) {
    console.log(event, "13rm")
    const { value } = event.target
    const text = value
}
```

Comment: The compiler will complaints: `Svelte: Property value does not exist on type EventTarget | null`

Answer (score 0):

Your edit is almost right, just change the `any` to `InputEvent`:

```js
  function emitChange(event: InputEvent) {
    console.log(event, "13rm")
    const { value } = event.target as HTMLInputElement
    const text = value
  }
```

Comment: funny, I am getting the following error: `Svelte: Argument of type  (e: InputEvent) => void  is not assignable to parameter of type  (e: CustomEvent<any>) => void` when attempt to: `<Input bind:value={email} on:input={onEmailChange}/>`

Comment: @GregWozniak Your `Input` is a custom component. Try to use HTML `<input>` element.