# How to type the event from on:input (from HTML Input element in Svelte) with JSDoc?

Tags: javascript, typescript, svelte, jsdoc

I'm trying to type an event that I receive from a Svelte-managed input element, but TypeScript tells me that my JSDoc type is incompatible with what I receive from the `on:input`. In my page code I have an input field with the following handler:

```html
<input id="description" on:input={handleInput}
```

And in JavaScript I have:

```js
/** @param {InputEvent & { target: HTMLInputElement}} event */
const handleInput = (event) => {
  const fullInput = event.target.value;
  const singleChar = event.data;
  const cursorPosition = event.target.selectionStart;
  // ...
```

In handleInput() the types are recognised correctly. But TypeScript shows this error on on:input in the HTML:

```
Type '(event: InputEvent & {    target: HTMLInputElement;}) => void' is not assignable to type 'FormEventHandler<HTMLInputElement>'.
  Types of parameters 'event' and 'event' are incompatible.
    Type 'Event & { currentTarget: EventTarget & HTMLInputElement; }' is not assignable to type 'InputEvent & { target: HTMLInputElement; }'.
      Type 'Event & { currentTarget: EventTarget & HTMLInputElement; }' is missing the following properties from type 'InputEvent': data, dataTransfer, inputType, isComposing, and 5 more.js(2322)
```

Why are these types incompatible and what can I do about this?

Comment: And which framework is this (remember to add its tag)? Because `on:input` is not plain HTML, and frameworks tend to put their own code in place.

Comment: btw. i've put my comments under the first answer. I'm using Svelte.

Comment: Next time, don't just comment, but [edit] your post to add the necessary tags. Otherwise the people who get notified about Svelte questions (or any other topic you're asking about) are unlikely to see it.

Comment: Sorry, has been some time since i did some coding, let alone posted something here. I've updated the post with what i think is the answer.

Comment: _Absolutely_ don't do that. Post your answer [as an answer](/help/how-to-answer) (with proper formatting of course: by posting to SO your question is not "for you", it's "for you _and everyone else in the future with the same problem_, so spend the effort to properly write/format your answer post) and then you can accept that answer so that searches (both here and on google and friends) surface this post as a complete question with answer. I've rolled back your edit, [so take that text](/posts/77303880/revisions) and put it in the answer you already wrote, instead.

Comment: Done. I was aware that this is for everyone else, so that's why i wrote  a proper answer (i think), just in the wrong place. I've also changed the title to include Svelte. Hope i've done everything ok now. SO tells me i have to wait 10 hours to accept my anwers. Thx.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is the JSDoc @param definition to use:

```js
/** @param {Event & {currentTarget: EventTarget & HTMLInputElement} & {target: HTMLInputElement} & InputEvent} event */
```

Explanation:
Just to see the type change on:input to `on:input={(e)=> e }` and hover over `e`. You will get the exact type that is expected (copy/paste-ready for JSDoc @param).

In this case it was:
`{Event & {currentTarget: EventTarget & HTMLInputElement}`

This solves the TS error on on:input, but it creates TS errors on:

```
const fullInput = event.target.value;
const singleChar = event.data;
const cursorPosition = event.target.selectionStart;
```

Because .data and .target is not a property on Event, but on InputEvent. See explanation why Svelte is not using InputEvent [here](https://github.com/sveltejs/language-tools/issues/1257). And .target should be typed as HTMLInputElement (like .currentTarget) By adding `& {target: HTMLInputElement} & InputEvent` you can add these types and TS doesn't complain any more. Not sure if this is good practice though.

Hope this helps others. Thank you Mike 'Pomax' Kamermans and jonrsharpe and the Svelte Discord channel.

Answer (score 0):

A typical JSDoc line for an `oninput` event in JavaScript can be done in three ways that I can think of. Most importantly, if you are saving your function to a variable (for example `const func = () => "hello"`, a.k.a. a function expression), you cannot use the JSDoc `@param` keyword. Instead you must use the special JSDoc function expression syntax as shown in the following examples.

► If the event handler is a function expression:

```
/**@type{(event:Event)=>void}*/
const handleInput = event => {
  // do stuff...
};
```

► An alternative function expression syntax:

```
/**@type{function(Event):void}*/
const handleInput = event => {
  // do stuff...
};
```

► And lastly, if the event handler is a function declaration:

```
/**
 * @param {Event} event
 * @return void
 */
function handleInput(event) {
  // do stuff...
}
```

Comment: Note that this is not the HTML `oninput` attribute, it's some framework's custom `on:input` property.

Comment: @Mike'Pomax'Kamermans I saw that but I'm hoping my examples will help OP get closer to what they're looking for

Comment: In absence of them updating their post with the specific framework they're using, really the solution is "type it as `@param {FormEventHandler<HTMLInputElement>} event` instead" since that's what TS flagged it as being.

Comment: Thanks for responding this fast. I am using Svelte as framework (and i wasn't aware that Svelte was providing it). When i change the type like this 
` @param {import('svelte/elements.js').FormEventHandler & { target: HTMLInputElement}}` 
i get `Generic type 'FormEventHandler' requires 1 type argument(s).js(2314)`

Comment: Think this is a similar question, though not with JSDoc. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/72339759/right-typescript-type-for-onchange-handler-in-svelte

Comment: After looking at that example i still don't get how i set the correct type. And thanks @user3163495 for the explanation, wasn't aware of that difference.

Comment: Btw. looking at this i shouldn't be using InputEvent anyway https://github.com/sveltejs/language-tools/issues/1257. Though using Event doesn't work as well.